# Ignore blank cells excel using if

Tags: excel

I honestly don't see what I am doing wrong here. I am trying to see the minimum between three cells, and I want the result to ignore if one of those cells is blank or return nothing if they are all blank.

I've tried (with an without spaces between the "")

```
=IF(ISBLANK("B21,B26,B31")," ",MIN(B21,B26,B31))
```

This gives me 0 if my cells are blank

I also tried

```
 =IF((ISBLANK("E21,E26,E31"))),(MIN(E21,E26,E31),"")
```

Which doesn't do anything. I don't know how this can be wrong and it's obviously not a difficult problem but I can't seem to crack it despite the huge number of people who have asked similar questions before.

Thanks in advance

Lilou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AND() inside the IF:

```
=IF(AND(B21="",B26="",B31=""),"",MIN(B21,B26,B31))
```

All three must resove true for it to put `""` in the cell or it will do the MIN().